# Under which conditions two groups of order $n=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$ are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory

$G,H$ two groups of order $n=2 \cdot  3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot  11 \cdot 13$ under which of the following conditions $G$ isomorphic to $H$ (prove or give a counterexample)

1) $G,H$ have have same factor groups

2) $G,H$ are solvable

3) $G,H$ are nil-potent

4) $G,H$ are abelian

5) $G,H$ are cyclic .

my intuition so far.

3)nil-potent groups are isomorphic because all sylow-p subgroups are normal and unique. 
4)abelian implies nil-potent hence $G$ and $H$ isomorphic (of order n otherwise not true).
5)last one is true because two cyclic groups of the same order are always isomorphic.

I would like some help proving/disproving the first two conditions.
i think groups that have trivial subnormal series $\{e\} \triangleleft G$ so the only factor group will be $G/\{e\} = G$ is a counter example but i'm not sure .

Comment: how do i use itemize environment on satckexchange ? i just tried the usual way it didnt work

Comment: Just above the window where you write your question there is a toolbar.

Comment: The second one is clearly not true. Just take $$S_3\times C_5\times C_7\times C_{11}\times C_{13},$$ and the cyclic group.

Comment: (3)-(4)-(5) Are true and practically the same: if $\;G,H\;$ are nilpotent then they're the direct product of their Sylow subgroups, which is then abelian as these subgroups are, in this case, cyclic of prime order , so $\;G,H\;$ are in fact abelian and, in fact again, cyclic as the product of cyclic groups of coprime order is cyclic.

Comment: (1) isn't clear to me: what does "having the same factor groups" mean? All the homomorphic images or composition series factors or what?

Comment: composition series factors (sorry is i was unclear i got the name from wikipedia)

Comment: If by factor groups you mean composition factors, then Ofir Schnabel's example is also a counterexample for (1).