# When are same order groups are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory

So the question is as follow:

> $G,H$ are two groups of order $n=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$ are G,H isomorphic if:
>
> (a) $G,H$ have to same composition factors
>
> (b) $G,H$ are solvable
>
> (c) $G,H$ are nilpotents
>
> (d) $G,H$ are abelian
>
> (e) $G,H$ are cyclic

So I've reached the follow conclusions:

for (d) the answer is now because we can take $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb  Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb  Z/3\mathbb Z \times\mathbb  Z/5\mathbb Z \times\mathbb  Z/7\mathbb Z \times\mathbb  Z/11\mathbb Z \times\mathbb  Z/13\mathbb Z $  which aren't isomorphic.

for (e) we can define a function from one group's generator to the other and it'll be isomorphism, so yes.

Now I'm having trouble with (a) - (d) though I saw a theorem I'm not sure how to prove that states the if $G,H$ are solvable with the same order then they have the same composition factors which makes (b) dependent on (a). any help with the rest will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120050/under-which-conditions-two-groups-of-order-n-2-cdot-3-cdot-5-cdot-7-cdot-11?rq=1.

Comment: Also, since 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 are relatively prime, you'll find that the product of these cyclic groups is, in fact, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

false up to b, true from c.

For c note that a nilpotent group is the direct product of it's sylow subgroups. For a counterexample to b see the comments in the post given by @HSN - the counterexample is $S_3\times C_5\times C_7\times C_{11}\times C_{13}$.

You're mistake on d is that the second group you mention is cyclic (generated by $(1,1,\ldots,1)$).

Comment: why am I wrong on (d) if the second group is cyclic then it is abelian and fits the criteria. also can you elaborate on (a) and (b)?

Comment: I understand that the counterexample works for (b) but for (a) how do you show that $C_n$ has the same composition factors as $S_3 \times C_5 \times C_7 \times C_{11} \times C_{13} $ ?

Comment: For (d), it fits the criteria, but it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ so is not a counterexample. As you noted any two solvable groups of the same order have the same composition factors. Alternatively, note $C_3$ is a normal subgroup of $S_3$ with quotient $S_3/C_3\cong C_2$ so you get composition series $1<C_3<S_3<S_3\times C_5<\cdots<S_3\times C_5\times\cdots\times C_{13}$